# iOS Objective C In-App Restore Function Use of undeclared identifier 'self'

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine, in-app

I'm new to iOS, basically I'm a Unity Game developer and I'm trying to integrating In-App purchase natively instead of using Unity IAP (due to some reasons). I'm developing native iOS plugin written in objective-c that can communicate with Unity, which is working fine. I had developed that plugin which is working fine, but now I'm adding restore purchase functionality. I found following solution on different sites on google.

```
@implementation IAPNativeCall

// inapp initialization and purchasing code.........

void restoreFunc(){
    request = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] init];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}

extern "C"
{
    void restorePurchases(){
        restoreFunc();
    }
}

@end
```

But on `request.delegate = self;` this line Xcode is throwing this error `Use of undeclared identifier 'self'` I'm googling it from morning and didn't found any solution on it. Following is my **"IAPNativeCall.h"** class code.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "StoreKit/StoreKit.h"

@interface IAPNativeCall : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>

@property (strong, nonatomic) SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;
@end
```

I'm stuck hare. Please help me if anyone know how to solve this issue.

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Where are you setting the delegate? Can you edit your question to include the method that the code `request.delegate = self;` belongs to?

Comment: I had updated my code. :)

Comment: `self` is not available in static function.

Comment: There are bunch of problems here. But the problem with the use of the `self` keyword is that you've declared `restoreFunc` as a C function, not an Objective-C method. There's no notion of `self` in C; it's not an object oriented language. Are you trying to write an Objective-C class that provides an external C API for your client to use? Or a pure Objective-C class?

Comment: I'm trying to write a pure objective-c class. And ignore `restorFunc()` It is working fine with unity and as well as for objective-c.